# how to ignore forward slash from django URL in a parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, restful-url

I am using django version 2.2.5. Below is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('manifest/', views.home),
   path('manifest/<str:some_id>/', views.manifest),
]
```

It works fine when some_id does not contain any forward slash(/). E.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest/name:19.2.4:develop:1/

In the following manifest function from views.py, I am able to get the some_id

```
def manifest(request, some_id):
     print(some_id)

##prints below:
##[21/Oct/2019 19:36:55] "GET /manifest/name:19.2.4:develop:1 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
##name:19.2.4:develop:1
```

However, when the some_id contains forward slash in it, I don't get the whole id. E.g., from the above URL if I would replace "develop" with "release/19.2.4" http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest/name:19.2.4:release/19.2.4:1/

```
"GET /manifest/name:19.2.4:release/19.2.4:1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3080
```

This is because of the forward slash being used as delimiter. Is there any way to ignore this forward slash inside of the some_id parameter? The expectation is to get **name:19.2.4:release/19.2.4:1** as **some_id** in the views.py

Note: The format of a valid some_id is it has 4 parts delimited by ":". e.g.: ***name:version:branch:num***, where only the branch section could have one or more slash(/) in it.

Comment: You can be specific and use a [regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions) instead of just path, or you can use `path` instead of `str` as [path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) which allows for forward-slashes.

Comment: @dirkgroten. Thanks. ```path``` does the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use good ol' [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/urls/#re-path)
In your case, that'll give

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('manifest/', views.home),
   re_path(r'manifest/(?P<some_id>\w+)/', views.manifest),
]
```

Your URL is structured though, have you tried something like:

```py
path('manifest/<str:name>:<str:version>:<path:branch>:<str:num>/', views.manifest),
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good point, since the URL is structured in this case. ```path('manifest/<str:name>:<str:version>:<path:branch>:<str:num>/', views.manifest),``` I am going to use the above, will replace str with ```path``` only for the branch part, since it can contain forward slash ("/")